# layout for different screen sizes

Tags: android

[image: This is what appears]\ [image: This is what I want]

I have read all the documents, I have read many stuff in stackoverflow as well as other places.

But still I cant get my foot out of this mud. I have made an app which up till now, I tested on my Nexus 5. Now as it is almost completed, I want to make it compatible with varous phones, and hence varous screen sizes.

When I tested my app on Nexus S (it is 4" / 400 x 800) everything appeared large and nothing fit in the screen as expected. So I created another layout named layout-small and adjusted the font sizes and all that. But again in Nexus S, the layout from default layout folder was used and not from the layout-small folder.

Can anyone please spend a couple of minutes to explain me this "Multiple screen sizes support" and what is the best approach to do so??

Thank you

Default layout folder :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="25sp"
    android:background="#009688">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:id="@+id/linear">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="35sp"
            android:id="@+id/mission"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MISSION"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="65sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/mission"
            android:id="@+id/notimpossible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NOT IMPOSSIBLE"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/random_main"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ahead"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Go Ahead! "
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_focus_white"
        android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout-small folder (with smaller font sizes and paddings)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:background="#009688">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:id="@+id/linear">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/mission"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MISSION"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/mission"
            android:id="@+id/notimpossible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NOT IMPOSSIBLE"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="8sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/random_main"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ahead"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Go Ahead! "
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_focus_white"
        android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to make a single responsive layout with linear or relative layouts.Divide the layouts and try to use `fill_parent` as width wherever you can..this will make the ui responsive..

Comment: If you post your code we might be able to point you in the right direction. My guess is that it has something to do with the layout you are using. You are not perhaps using `AbsoluteLayout` are you?

Comment: @Lal - it wont work for font sizes. They will remain the same and hence wil appear too large in smaller devices

Comment: The `res/layout-small` folder is used for small screens. These are screens that are less than 320x470dp, which does not apply to the Nexus S. You should be specifying layout sizes in dp and font sizes in sp. That way the sizes will scale correctly based on the device's pixel density and the user's preferred font size setting, without you having to adjust the layout for each device.

Comment: @TedHopp i have used sp for font sizes. but still they appear to large in Nexus S... what about using layout-sw320dp and all that stuff? any idea about that?

Comment: Can you post some screen shots showing what you want it to look like and what actually appears?

Comment: @TedHopp posted... the pic above is what I am getting and the pic below is what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

create

```
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi
layout-xxxhdpi
```

folders for different dpi's. For different sizes, you can use

```
layout-small (for small size phones)
layout-normal (for normal size phones)
layout-large (for 7 inch tablets)
layout-xlarge (for 10 inch tablets)
```

and also use like

```
layout-large-hdpi
layout-large-mdpi
layout-xlarge-hdpi
layout-xlarge-mdpi
```

for nexus S you neet to use layout-normal or layout-hdpi

Comment: thank you very much... this is what I was looking for... can u please explain which approach is better and what to use for what phone?

Comment: if nexus S uses layout-large, then what about nexus 5?

Comment: nexus S, 4, 5 are use layout-normal.  Use layout-large for 7 inch tablets and layout-xlarge for 10 inch tablets. Using layout-hdpi is better for you. I use folders for dpi. If You support tablets, you should add layout-large and layout-xlarge folders.

Answer (score 2):

if you have same layout, you don't need to create multiple layout xml.
you can adjust text-size (or various dimension params) by dimens.xml

example

res/layout/your_activity.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_large"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"/>
```

res/values/dimens.xml

```
<!-- this is common parameter -->
<dimen name="text_small">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="space_large">8dp</dimen>
```

res/values-large/dimens.xml

```
<!-- for large-size display -->
<dimen name="text_small">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="space_large">12dp</dimen>
```

this approach sometimes effective.

if your layout change significantly by display size, you should choose multiple layout-xml style, as @oguzhand says.

Comment: + 1 your solution is useful too... as in my case where most of the adjustments are to be done with font sizes... however, the above solution gives more flexibility...